# and bitwise operator in C preprocessor

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

When I try the following code:

```
#if 11 & 10 == 10
#endif
```

the evaluation of expression is true but when I change that to the following:

```
#if 10 & 10 == 10
#endif
```

The evaluation returns false, while based on definition of & operator it should still return true (when I am trying out of preprocessor that's correct). 
Generally, Whatever I am trying which has 0 in the first operand returns false ignoring what the result is.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 7):

[Order of operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) seems to be the culprit since `==` is evaluated before `&`. Parentheses worked for me:

```
#if (10 & 10) == 10
```

Answer (score 5):

`==` has higher precedence than `&`

`if 11 & 10 == 10` evaluates to `if 11 & 1` evaluates to `if 1`

`if 10 & 10 == 10` evaluates to `if 10 & 1` evaluates to `if 0`